# Are Party Members skills missable?

Tags: persona-3-fes, persona-3-portable

Minor spoiler warning for those of you haven't played Persona 3.

At various points in the game, the party members will upgrade their Personas. The new Persona will have better stats and give them access to stronger moves.

For example, Ken's initial persona, Nemesis, learns its final skill, Recarm, at level 42. However, Ken's Ultimate persona, Kala-Nemi learns an additional 8 moves, starting with Mediarama at level 51.

What happens if you level your party members up too much? Like, you level Ken up to 52 before he upgrades his Persona. Would he never get Mediarama? Or would they just learn any such moves all at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I happened to be only a couple of levels from it happening, I decided to try it out with Fuuka, and then had her persona evolve.

It doesn't pop up to show you that they've learned new moves, but the skill list is what it should've been had you not been overleveled. Party skills are not missable.

Answer (score 0):

My uneducated guess is that it would come with the "best" skills it could have learned up to that point. So Mediarama and the rest would automatically replace Media and the rest of the skills they would replace through normal leveling automatically. This is especially likely since you don't control your party members leveling up or the the skills they choose anyway.